# PayPal IPN Listener Working with sandbox but not live

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a paypal ipn listener ipn.php, which is linked to a database and updates the notifications table with the notification info and then emails a key to the payer email.

Here's the ipn.php

```
<?php    

include("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php");

include("config.php");

    //Send an empty HTTP 200 OK response to acknowledge receipt of the notification

ini_set("log_errors", "On");
ini_set("error_log", "error.log");

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);

if($con == false){ echo "Could not connect to mysql: " . mysql_error();}
else{echo "Connected to database successfully!";}

header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
header('Connection: close');


$item_name        = $_POST['item_name'] != null ? $_POST['item_name'] : "none"; 
$item_number      = $_POST['item_number'] != null ? $_POST['item_number'] : "none";
$payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'] != null ? $_POST['payment_status'] : "none";
$payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'] != null ? $_POST['mc_gross'] : "none";
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'] != null ? $_POST['mc_currency'] : "none";
$txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id'] != null ? $_POST['txn_id'] : "none";
$receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email'] != null ? $_POST['receiver_email'] : "none";
$payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'] != null ? $_POST['payer_email'] : "none";

// Build the required acknowledgement message out of the notification just received
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // Add 'cmd=_notify-validate' to beginning of the acknowledgement

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode these values
    $req  .= "&$key=$value";                   // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
}

// Set up the acknowledgement request headers
$header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";     // HTTP POST request
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// Send the HTTP POST request back to PayPal for validation
fputs($fp, $header . $req);


    error_log("reached");

    $res = stream_get_contents($fp,1024);           // Get the acknowledgement response

    while(!feof($fp)){
        $res = trim(fgets($fp,1024));

        if(empty($res)){
            break;
        }
    }

    $res = trim(fgets($fp,1024));

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  // Response contains VERIFIED - process notification


        $sql = "INSERT INTO notifications VALUES( DEFAULT, '$item_name','$item_number','$payment_status','$payment_amount','$payment_currency','$txn_id','$receiver_email','$payer_email')";

        mysql_select_db($dbname,$con);

        if(!mysql_query($sql)){
            error_log(mysql_error());
        }

        if(strcmp($payment_status,"Completed") == 0){
            mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
            $key = get_new_key();
            $sql = "";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO activationkeys VALUES(DEFAULT, '$key', '0', $item_number)";
            if(!mysql_query($sql)){
                error_log("Could not execute query: " . mysql_error());
            }

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            //Send mail using gmail
            if($config_gmail){
                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
                $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                $mail->Port = 587;
                $mail->Username = $config_gmail_username;
                $mail->Password = $config_gmail_password;
            }

            //Typical mail data
            $mail->AddAddress($payer_email,"Donator");
            $mail->SetFrom($config_merchant_domain,$config_merchant_name);
            $mail->Subject = "You're Donation Key";
            $mail->Body = "Hey, your payment was successful.\nHere's your key: " . $key;

            if(!$mail->send()){
                error_log("Message could not be sent: " . $mail->ErrorInfo );
            }


        }
        mysql_close($con);



        // Authentication protocol is complete - OK to process notification contents

        // Possible processing steps for a payment include the following:

        // Check that the payment_status is Completed
        // Check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // Check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        // Check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // Process payment

    } 
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) { //Response contains INVALID - reject notification

        // Authentication protocol is complete - begin error handling
        // Send an email announcing the IPN message is INVALID
        $mail_From    = "IPN@example.com";
        $mail_To      = "Your-eMail-Address";
        $mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
        $mail_Body    = $req;

        mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
    }

fclose($fp);  // Close the file

function get_new_key(){
    $keycharacters = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $key = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $key .= $keycharacters[rand(0,strlen($keycharacters)-1)];
    }
    return $key;
}

?>
```

The problem is, when I send through the sandbox it updates the databse fine and emails the key, but when I try and use the code live it doesn't do anything...

I'm at a loss as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Get any error? Checked IPN history logs?if making API calls, make sure to use LIVE Credentials, if still problem get me the Account number or email address, or raise ticket to paypal.com/mts

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it, the problem was with the way I was reading the response, I now use;

```
if (!$fp) {  
        error_log("could not open socket"); 
    } else {  
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);  
        while (!feof($fp)) {  
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);  
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```